# MySQL - Query to merge rows in table with duplicate values in on field

Tags: mysql, merge

I'm quite new on data bases and would be very grateful for some help, I have a database on the following format:

```
ID     Nbr     Data1     Data2    Data3
1      1       a    
2      1                 b
3      1                          c
4      2       d    
5      2                 e
6      2                          f
```

And would like to have a way to extract, with a MySQL query, the data on the following format:

```
Nbr     Data1     Data2    Data3
1       a         b        c
2       d         e        f
```

I know that is not best practice to have the data on a non normalized format but sadly I can't change the source data.

Grateful for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Insert into newtable 
    select ID,Nbr,max(Data1),max(Data2),max(Data3) from table group by Nbr
```

Try this and let me know it worked or not

Comment: you have to watch out for nulls

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT Nbr, 
           Max(data1) data1, 
           Max(data2) data2, 
           Max(Data3) data3 
    FROM   table 
    GROUP  BY Nbr
```